# Split string, convert ToList<int>() in one line

Tags: c#, list, split

I have a string that has numbers

```
string sNumbers = "1,2,3,4,5";
```

I can split it then convert it to `List<int>`

```
sNumbers.Split( new[] { ',' } ).ToList<int>();
```

How can I convert string array to integer list?
So that I'll be able to convert `string[]` to `IEnumerable`

Comment: We had exactly the same question today: [Click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910119/how-to-create-a-listt-from-a-comma-seperated-string)

Comment: in "one line" si a very strong is a very strict requirement! </perl>

Comment: This question specifically says to split a string of numbers, which keeps the answer simple. The question Dario mentioned handles (bogs down in?) issues of TryParse for general strings.

Answer (score 620, accepted):

```
var numbers = sNumbers?.Split(',')?.Select(Int32.Parse)?.ToList();
```

Recent versions of C# (v6+) allow you to do null checks in-line using the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Comment: This get Exception when the List has empty value or null.

Comment: @SayedM.Idrees just check null or empty before splitting.

Comment: add a null check: var numbers = sNumbers?.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect null checks as mentioned by @MichaelG

Comment: How to convert it to List<long>? Select(Int64.Parse) is showing error.

Answer (score 43):

Better use `int.TryParse` to avoid exceptions;

```
var numbers = sNumbers
            .Split(',')
            .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _))
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 40):

You can also do it this way without the need of Linq:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>( Array.ConvertAll(sNumbers.Split(','), int.Parse) );

// Uses Linq
var numbers = Array.ConvertAll(sNumbers.Split(','), int.Parse).ToList();
```

Answer (score 20):

Joze's way also need LINQ, `ToList()` is in `System.Linq` namespace.

You can convert Array to List without Linq by passing the array to List constructor:

```cs
List<int> numbers = new List<int>( Array.ConvertAll(sNumbers.Split(','), int.Parse) );
```

Answer (score 13):

It is also possible to int array to direct assign value.

like this

```
int[] numbers = sNumbers.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use new C# 6.0 Language Features:

- replace delegate `(s) => { return Convert.ToInt32(s); }` with 
  corresponding method group `Convert.ToInt32`
- replace redundant constructor call: `new Converter<string, int>(Convert.ToInt32)` with: `Convert.ToInt32`

The result will be:

```
var intList = new List<int>(Array.ConvertAll(sNumbers.Split(','), Convert.ToInt32));
```

Answer (score 4):

also you can use this Extension method

```
public static List<int> SplitToIntList(this string list, char separator = ',')
{
    return list.Split(separator).Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
}
```

usage:

```
var numberListString = "1, 2, 3, 4";
List<int> numberList = numberListString.SplitToIntList(',');
```

Answer (score 3):

On Unity3d, `int.Parse` doesn't work well. So I use like bellow.

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>( Array.ConvertAll(sNumbers.Split(','),
 new Converter<string, int>((s)=>{return Convert.ToInt32(s);}) ) );
```

Hope this help for Unity3d Users.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was similar but with the inconvenience that sometimes the string contains letters (sometimes empty).

```
string sNumbers = "1,2,hh,3,4,x,5";
```

Trying to follow Pcode Xonos Extension Method:

```
public static List<int> SplitToIntList(this string list, char separator = ',')
{
      int result = 0;
      return (from s in list.Split(',')
              let isint = int.TryParse(s, out result)
              let val = result
              where isint
              select val).ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although you declare a separator and then you don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

Why stick with just int when we have generics?
What about an extension method like :

```
    public static List<T> Split<T>(this string @this, char separator, out bool AllConverted)
    {
        List<T> returnVals = new List<T>();
        AllConverted = true;
        var itens = @this.Split(separator);
        foreach (var item in itens)
        {
            try
            {
                returnVals.Add((T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T)));
            }
            catch { AllConverted = false; }
        }
        return returnVals;
    }
```

and then

```
 string testString = "1, 2, 3, XP, *, 6";
 List<int> splited = testString.Split<int>(',', out _);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

```
List<Int32> sNumberslst = sNumbers.Split(',').ConvertIntoIntList();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: The function ConvertIntoIntList doesn't exits.

Comment: Also, you need to add the following class:

 static public class HelperMethods
{
    static public List<int> ConvertIntoIntList(this string[] stringList)
    {
        int x = 0;
        var intList = stringList.Where(str => int.TryParse(str, out x))
                                .Select(str => x)
                                .ToList();
        return intList;
    }
}