# what is the best way in C# to convert string into int[]

Tags: c#, arrays, string, int, string-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string, convert ToList<int>() in one line…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911717/split-string-convert-tolistint-in-one-line)

i have a string that looks like this.

```
string s = "1,6,4,3,5,7,4";
```

and i want to convert this into an array of integers.

what is the best and fastest way of doing this in C#?

Comment: I don't know about fastest, but in C#4, a terse way would be: `var nums =  Array.ConvertAll(s.Split(','), int.Parse);`

Comment: @jleedev, technically, the dup doesn't address converting it to an *array*.  But...the OP can just tack on `.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use split method.

```
int[] array = s.Split(',').Select(str => int.Parse(str)).ToArray();
```

Hmm, don't know if it is fastest way, however it is the simplest way :)

Comment: you can use `.Select(int.Parse)` instead of `.Select(str => int.Parse(str))`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

```
int[] i = Array.ConvertAll(s.Split(','), new Converter<string, int>(delegate (string str) { return int.Parse(str); } ));
```

Comment: This does not convert it into an array of `int`.

Comment: Which results in an array of strings

Comment: My apologies for not reading the question properly... I'd stick to @Danil's answer.