# How I can convert string[] to list<int>?

Tags: c#, arrays

How I can convert an array of strings to list of int?  (without converting them one by one with my own method)

From searching in google I've seen methods named ToList() and ConvetAll() but I cant typed them, why is that?

What I've tried is:

`new list<int>((int[])s.Split(','));`

and I'm getting error that i cant convert string[] to int[] :(

Comment: What do your strings look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string, convert ToList<int>() in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911717/split-string-convert-tolistint-in-one-line)

Answer (score 44):

There's a two-step process involved here. The first is to convert the strings to an integer, then convert the array to a list. If you can use LINQ, the easiest way is to use:

```
stringArray.Select(x => Int32.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: or shorter: `stringArray.Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();`

Comment: In case anyone wants to include a `TryParse`to prevent exceptions:
'int i; List<int> intList = stringArray.Split(',').Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out i) ? i : -1).ToList();`

Answer (score 19):

Getting a hint from your code:

```
var listOfInts = s.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
var result = s.Split(',').Select(Convert.ToInt32).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Using

```
int x = 0; 

var intList= stringList.Where(str => int.TryParse(str, out x)).Select(str => x).ToList();
```

Comment: There is an easier way: using `Array.ConvertAll` method

Answer (score 1):

For VB.NET, I had to do it in a loop

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Integer)
For Each item As String In s.Split(",")
    myList.Add(Val(item))
Next
```

May have been able to work it out with some inbuilt function but didn't want to spend too much time on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<int > M1()
{
    string[] s =(file path));
    Array.Sort(s);
    var c = new List<int>();
    foreach(string x in s)
    {
        c.Add(Convert.ToInt32(x));
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Please add some description.

Answer (score 1):

use the following code:

```
var list = s.Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
```

Comment: the shortest one so far

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `values` is your list of strings:

```
int[] ints = new int[values.Count];

int counter = 0;
foreach (string s in values) {
    ints[counter++] = int.Parse(s);
}
```

Don't overcomplicate yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 var selectedEditionIds = input.SelectedEditionIds.Split(",").ToArray()
                        .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i) 
                         && int.TryParse(i,out int validNumber))
                        .Select(x=>int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `Array.ConvertAll` method. `Array.ConvertAll` converts an array of one type to an array of another.

Here is the code:

```
string[] strArray = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
int[] intArray = Array.ConvertAll(strArray, int.Parse);
```