# Convert string of numbers separated by commas into a List<int>?

Tags: c#, string, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string, convert ToList<int>() in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911717/split-string-convert-tolistint-in-one-line)
>   [Convert comma separated string of ints to int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763613/convert-comma-separated-string-of-ints-to-int-array)

I have a string like:
`string test = "1,2,3,4";`

Is there any easier way (syntactically) to convert it to a `List<int>` equivalent to something like this:

```
string[] testsplit  = test.Split(',');
List<int> intTest = new List<int>();
foreach(string s in testsplit)
    intTest.Add(int.Parse(s));
```

Comment: Like, "splitting" it? I've updated the tags, to get you on your way with related questions.

Comment: Never seen so many identical answers, jeez.

Answer (score 9):

You can throw LINQ at it:

```
List<int> intTest = test.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

It first splits the string, then parses each part(returning an `IEnumerable<int>`) and finally constructs a list from the integer sequence.

Comment: +1. The only thing I would change is to use a method group rather than lambda. `.Select(int.Parse).ToList()`

Comment: @32bitkid And you'd leave the explicit type signature? :( Anyway, this will work with the example, but there are fun edge-cases, like "," and ",1", not to mention any invalid int.

Comment: @pst I'd consider those cases as invalid input. If you want to handle invalid input you need `TryParse` and the code gets much uglier.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = test.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x));
```

Or, if you really want a `List<int>` (rather than just any `IEnumerable<int>`), append a `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

`test.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

Linq can make it a bit cleaner:

```
var intTest = test.Split(',').Select(s=>int.Parse(s)).ToList();
```