# LINQ - delete rows from database table from an Array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a comma seperated values (1, 2, 5, 8) and I am converting them into an array like this

```
string s =checkboxId.Value;
int[] nums = Array.ConvertAll(s.Split(','), int.Parse);
```

I want to delete all this rows where id is in nums. How can I do this with LINQ?

Tried this:

```
  foreach(int id in nums)
    {
   DeleteById(id, uid);
   }
   public void DeleteById(int id, string userName)
    {            
        long uid = common.GetUserId(userName);

        IEnumerable<M> idList = dataContext.MD.Where(m => m.ID == id && m.UserId == uid);
        dataContext.MD.DeleteAllOnSubmit(idList);
        dataContext.dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

**EDIT:**
 I do not want to loop through every array item. Is there a way where I can easily pass the array and delete all the records from the database through LINQ query?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where you want to delete from?

Comment: Delete row from where? And why linq?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string, convert ToList<int>() in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911717/split-string-convert-tolistint-in-one-line)

Answer (score 1):

Parse it to IEnumerable. Create new List with excluded values and then remove it with predicate in method RemoveAll.

An example:

```
        string s = checkboxId.Value;
        var nums = s.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .ToList();
        var toBeRemoved = new List<int>{1, 2, 5};
        var numberOfRemovedItems = nums.RemoveAll(toBeRemoved.Contains);
```

Comment: Good point, I never realized you can just pass a function instead of a full lambda

Comment: @BurnsBA after your comment, realized we could do the same with 'RemoveAll' :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
string s = checkboxId.Value;
int[] nums = Array.ConvertAll(s.Split(','), int.Parse);

 var uid = 1234;

 // I prefer LINQ syntax.  The lambda syntax is fine too.
 var idList = from m in dataContext.MD
              where m.UserId == uid && nums.Contains(m.id)
              select m;

dataContext.MD.DeleteAllOnSubmit(idList);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: it says nums does not have Contains

Comment: Be sure you have "using System.Linq;"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with linq:

```
var arr = s.Split(',').Where(n => n != checkboxId.Value)
                      .Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n))
                      .ToArray();
```

Comment: Why do you need `Where` clause? Condition `n != to checkboxId.Value` will always be true.

Comment: Actually, n would equal checkboxId.Value when there is no comma in checkboxId.Value (i.e., when just one value is given).  But you probably don't want to filter those out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have a string `1,2,5,8`

To convert this string to an array of `int`. You can do this. Attention if your string contains only `int`.

```
string s = "1,2,5,8";
var arrayInt = s.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
```

Next, you want to delete all these numbers in your array of int `ids`.

```
var arrayIntCleared = ids.ToList().Except(arrayInt);
```

Comment: No need to convert the array the Split() return into a List.  Also, Select takes function which takes a single object, and converts it to a different single object.  You can create such a function with a Lambda, as you did.  Or you can just use the one .NET gives you directly:
`var arrayInt = s.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Uid when you select:

```
var toDelete = checkboxId.Value
    .Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select( x => {
        int parsedInt= 0;
        var isInt = int.TryParse(x , out parsedInt);
        return new {isInt, parsedInt}
    })
    .Where(x => x.isInt)
    .Select(x=> new {Id= x.parsedInt, Uid=common.GetUserId(x.parsedInt)});

foreach(var item in toDelete)
{
    dataContext.MD.DeleteAllOnSubmit(
        dataContext.MD
            .Where(m => m.ID == item.Id && m.UserId == item.Uid)
        )
}
dataContext.dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Or without `int.TryParse` check:

```
var toDelete = checkboxId.Value
        .Split(',')
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .Select(x=> new {Id= x.parsedInt, Uid=common.GetUserId(x.parsedInt)})
```

For me the best way would be to have proper link between object in your dbml. So you can travel from on object to an other and you won't need neither `common.GetUserId()` or `m.ID == item.Id && m.UserId == item.Uid).First()`. 
with that done you could simply:

```
var idToDelete = checkboxId.Value
        .Split(',')
        .Select(int.Parse);

var entitiesToDelete = dataContext.MD
                        .Where(x => toDelete.Contains(x.Id));


dataContext.MD.DeleteAllOnSubmit(entitiesToDelete);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: is there a way where I can pass the array list and delete all the records whose ids are in array?

Comment: @user1254053, you can pass a `enumerable<object>` to `DeleteAllOnSubmit` and delete on the context. I suposse you are using Linq2 sql right ?

Comment: dbml and linq queries

Comment: I have edit my question with optimal simple code but .. Your question evole a little bit to much and to fast. It has invalidate most of the answer because you was not clear enought and hid part of the issue when you posted. You should edit this question to the duplicate it was when originaly post and post and other on clear  on the database delete. Stating that you already have the list of ID you wan't to delete. And be clear on the 1-1 or 1-n relation between Id and user ID

Comment: Thanks a lot xdtTransform for  your suggestion.