# How to convert a c# comma separated values string into a list?

Tags: c#

I'm using C# ASP.NET 4 and SQL Server 2008 R2

I'm getting an object scalar from sql server which is a string containing comma separated values of the form:

`7, 12, ... 1, 65`

I would like to convert this object into a list?

I thought of the direction:

`List<int> myList = new List<int>(new int[] (List)mySqlClass.mySqlQueryReturningAnObject("SELECT CLAUSE");`

but this is not going to work.

How do I convert this object into a list?

---

### Full answer:

This answer in use is according to the selected answer (before the update)

`List<int> myList = new List<int>(mySqlClass.mySqlQueryReturningAnObject("SELECT CLAUSE").ToString().Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList());`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a List<T> from a comma separated string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910119/how-to-create-a-listt-from-a-comma-separated-string)

Comment: Already covered on StackOverflow; hence vote to close.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var intValues = line.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
```

**Update**

To ensure your code would be able to process strings like `1,2,3,,,4,5,6` you can use overload of `String.Split` method

```
var intValues = line.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the .Split() method on the string.  It will return an array of strings.

```
string yourResult = "1,2,3,4,5";
string[] resultsArray = yourResult.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)?

You can split your string with a line as simple as this:

```
var myString="1,2,4,5,6";
var numberList=myString.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple [Array.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) instuction, like this:

```
string str = "1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9";
int[]resultInArray = Array.ConvertAll( str.Split(','), item => int.Parse(item));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        private void TestParse()
        {
            string commaseparatedstring = "3, 5,6,19";

            int parsedvalue = 0;

            List<int> valuesint =
                commaseparatedstring.Split(',').Select(elem => int.TryParse(elem, out parsedvalue) ? parsedvalue : 0).ToList(); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try assigning the result to a variable.

Then convert it into a string (if its not already one)

Then do a string split on the comma and assigning the results to a list.

Comment: I should learn the basics first. I'm looking for something like List<int> myList= myCSVstring.Split(',').ToList(); but this ivokes: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' and I do not find where to convert the string into an int.

Comment: Do you need them as an int? If not then just make your list a list of strings. In fact you could still do that and then when you read them out of the list you can do a Convert.ToInt32(listitem)

Comment: Yes I need them as ints. Yes, I did that, I read the string and convert them to ints upon read. Is there a syntax for doing it upon assitnment?

Comment: This article might help with that bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942/cast-listint-to-liststring-in-net-2-0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12699/discussion-between-gaz-winter-and-different111222)