# Comma separated string to generic list

Tags: c#, string, reflection, collections

I was able to convert comma separated string to an `IList<int>` but how can I modify the same to get `IList<T>` where T will be passed as one of the input parameter?

i.e if I need `IList<int>` I will pass "int" as parameter, if I need `IList<string>` I will pass "string" as parameter.

My idea is to get the type whether it is int or string through input parameter and use reflection and convert the string to respective list

***Code to convert comma separated string as `IList<int>`***

```
public static IList<int> SplitStringUsing(this string source, string seperator =",")
{
     return source.Split(Convert.ToChar(seperator))
                  .Select(x => x.Trim())
                  .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                  .Select(int.Parse).ToList();
}
```

**Note:** Above code isn't tested yet

I am looking for something like

```
public static IList<T> SplitStringUsing(this string source, string seperator =",", T t)
{
find the type of t and convert it to respective List
}
```

Comment: You don't need to trim if you are using IsNullOrWhitespace.

Comment: How about instead of providing a parameter `T t` you provide a "selector" function `Func<string, T>` and then use that in place of the `int.Parse`? So you could use it like `IList<int> list = "1, 2, 3, 4".SplitStringUsing(",", int.Parse);`. And if you need for example doubles, you can change it to `IList<double> list = "1, 2, 3, 4".SplitStringUsing(",", double.Parse);`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Convert.ChangeType(object,string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) for parsing to the base types supported by the [System.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert(v=vs.110).aspx) class, or any other class that implements the [IConvertible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx) interface

```
public static IList<T> SplitStringUsing<T>(string source, string seperator = ",")
where T:IConvertible
{
        return source.Split(Convert.ToChar(seperator))
                     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                     .Select(x=>Convert.ChangeType(x,typeof(T)))
                     .Cast<T>()
                     .ToList();
}
```

To avoid localization issues, you should probably add an IFormatProvider parameter as well, to allow the caller to specify the culture to use or default to the current culture, eg:

```
public static IList<T> SplitStringUsing<T>(string source, 
    string seperator = ",",
    IFormatProvider provider =null)
    where T:IConvertible
{
    return source.Split(Convert.ToChar(seperator))
                    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                    .Select(x=>Convert.ChangeType(x,typeof(T),provider))
                    .Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

For a more generic case, you can pass the parsing code as a lambda to the function:

```
    public static IList<T> SplitStringUsing<T>(string source, 
        Func<string,T> parser,  
        string seperator = ",")
    {
        return source.Split(Convert.ToChar(seperator))
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
            .Select(parser)
            .ToList();
    }
```

and call it like this:

```
var l1 = SplitStringUsing(x,s=>double.Parse(s,NumberStyles.HexNumber,
                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

You can have both methods in your code and the compiler will pick the correct overload.

Comment: this is a good solution if you know the type of data beforehand

Comment: That's what generic means in the context of C#. The function doesn't know the type and expects the caller to specify it

Comment: right.. question was confusing I thought he wants to determine type dynamically based on input

Comment: That's impossible for a small function - is 1 an int, long, float, double or decimal? A char or even a string? That requires determining parsing rules and fallbacks, knowing the context of the call (eg will the list be combined with other strings or numbers)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no I not finding the type based on value (1 or A) but I know during development whether I need Integer List or String List or Double List

Answer (score 2):

I think you need Convert.ChangeType, like this. Its not fully tested, compile and fix.

```
public static IList<T> SplitStringUsing(string source, string seperator =",")
    {
         return source.Split(Convert.ToChar(seperator))
                      .Select(x => x.Trim())
                      .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                      .Select((T)Convert.ChangeType( x, typeof( T ) )).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: This won't compile, because `ChangeType` returns `object`. You also need to cast the results to the proper type with `Cast<T>()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos he is doing the cast in Select. btw it needs a little modification: `.Select(x => (T)Convert.ChangeType( x, typeof( T ) )`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos (T) act as a Cast. But I am not sure, if it work. Thats why I had mentioned to compile and fix.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28233265/2968144) of @PanagiotisKanavos.

Especially the generic approach with:

```
public static class StringToListExtension
{
    //see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split.aspx
    //and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx

    //this is the generic approach offering enough possibilies to use
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> MapStringValues<TResult>(this String source, Func<String, TResult> itemMapper, String[] separator, StringSplitOptions options)
    {
        if (null == source) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        return source.Split(separator, options).Select(itemMapper);
    }

    //add your implementation using MapStringValues<T>
    public static IList<Int32> MapToInt32ListUsingParse(this String source, String[] separator, StringSplitOptions options)
    {
        return MapStringValues<Int32>(source, Int32.Parse, separator, options).ToList();
    }

    //or more convenient
    public static IList<Int32> DefaultMapToIntList(this String source)
    {
        return MapStringValues<Int32>(source, Int32.Parse, DefaultSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    }

    private static readonly String[] DefaultSeparator = new []{ "," };
}
```

You would use that code:

```
String values = "some,text,with,commas";
List<String> l1 = values.MapStringValues<String>(s => s, new []{ "," }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

values = "2,4,,5,6";
IList<Int32> l2 = values.MapToInt32ListUsingParse(new []{ "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

values = "2,4,,5,6";
IList<Int32> l3 = values.DefaultMapToIntList();
```

You can add convenience implementations for all your String to T cases. If you don't want exceptions to be thrown just implement a parse function using [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx), etc.